# Windows 10 LAN Traffic Won't Go via LAN GW when Cirtrix VPN is On

Tags: windows, vpn, routing, citrix

Env: Windows 10 pro on a 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Symptom: This PC won't be able to reach any LAN devices when the Citrix Gateway VPN is connected, even if the "Local LAN access" option on the client is enabled.

I think it's something caused by the routing table, however, while I'm reading the routing table, I found my LAN network actually is there. So if Windows match the address by the longest prefix match, it should be able to reach any local devices when the VPN is connected. Here is my `route print` output (I've removed pub IPs):

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1      10.45.50.80      1
         10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.45.50.80      1
      10.44.0.197  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
      10.44.0.198  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
      10.44.0.199  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
     10.45.21.189  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
     10.45.21.190  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
      10.45.50.80  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.45.50.80    257
     10.45.69.213  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
     10.45.69.214  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
    10.182.185.40  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
     192.168.1.1    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.1.114    271
     192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
   192.168.1.114  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
   192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.45.50.80    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.45.50.80    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       1
===========================================================================
```

This is the routing table once the VPN is disconnected:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.1.1   192.168.1.114     35
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.1.1    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.1.114    271
   192.168.1.114  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
   192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.1.114    291
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 14    291 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    291 fe80::750c:33a6:1c66:e99/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    291 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

`tracert` shows all the 192.168.1.0/24 next hop towards to 10.45.80.129.

Any idea of what caused this problem? If it can be fixed by manually adding a static route, what entry I should use?

Comment: Most VPN clients have an 'allow local network traffic' option or similar. Check you have the latest version and take a look in the settings

Comment: Yes, that option has already enabled on the client

Comment: Do you have another installed network adapter, wireless for example - that you can use instead to test? Disable the currently used physical adapter first.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas how to test it? could you describe it pls?

Comment: If you have wifi, connect to your ssid, disconnect lan cable and run vpn - vpn should now try and connect over wifi instead. see if same symptoms occur

Comment: Sorry, it's the same result